# I want a lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue of $AA^T$ in terms of the Frobenius norm of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, spectral-radius

Let $\lambda_n$ be smallest eigenvalue of the square matrix $AA^T$. How could I lower bound this in terms of Frobenius norm of $A$, i.e., getting a constant $c$ such that

$${\lambda _n}\left( {A{A^T}} \right) \ge c\left\| A \right\|_F^2$$

the square on the right hand side is a mere prediction. The matrix $A$ is not assumed to be symmetric. Assume also A is non-singular

Comment: The only option is $c=0$ since $AA^{\mathrm t}$ can be singular for non-zero $A$.

Comment: @WimC say it is non-singular

Comment: @Fethi As my answer explains, WimC's statement is correct, even in your amended context. Perhaps you should use some information involving the condition number of $A$.

Comment: Also, do we know that $A$ is a real matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only such constant is $c = 0$. Consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&\epsilon},
$$
which is non-singular for all $\epsilon \neq 0$. We have
$$
\lambda_n(AA^T) = \epsilon^2, \quad \|A\|_F^2 = 1 + \epsilon^2.
$$
Rearranging your inequality yields
$$
\frac{\lambda_n(AA^T)}{\|A\|_F^2} \geq c \implies\frac{\epsilon^2}{1 + \epsilon^2} \geq c.
$$
However, as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, the left-hand side approaches $0$.